How to rotate text in an excel cell using NPOI 2.7.1
I can't see any change in the text in my cell. Does someone know why?
ICellStyle teststyle = workbook.CreateCellStyle();
teststyle.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
teststyle.Rotation = 90; 
var testx = worksheet.CreateRow(12);
testx.HeightInPoints = 100;
var celltest = testx.CreateCell(0);
celltest.SetCellValue("TESTX");
celltest.CellStyle = teststyle;

I try with add more HeightPoints but didn´t work.

Nothing wrong with the code. I tried it and it works. HOw are you trying to save the file? As .xls or .xlsx?

Can you also include the code where you are initialising workbook & worksheet. I would also like to see the Save code if possible.
